# Is the StackExchange forum template available for other websites than their network?

Tags: support, licensing

I would like to know if there might be the possibility to use the StackExchange page setup as a template in a website. Is there any licence (with page setup & code) which might be available for purchase?

Comment: To all downvotes, I checked for answers before but couldn't find any, it seams that a similar question has been asked 3 years ago. But even so, don't you think that it would be still possible that the answers or the conditions might have changed meanwhile. Why the downvotes for something which is based not on coding but on business decision?
Any website with banner ads is out there to make money and the management can change their oppinion of how to improve their income or gain more money out of it  at any given moment. Anyone who understands something about business will tell you the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No, you cannot license the Stack Exchange platform code for your own purposes.

Long answer: You used to be able to do this, in the days of Stack Exchange 1.0. Now that we're on 2.0, if you want a new site you need to go to [area51.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), propose it, and get support for it. Stack Exchange wants to create sites with community support behind them that are likely to succeed. If you think you have an idea for one, go propose it!

Comment: So, downvotes signify disagreement. What's to disagree with here?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yeah... I don't know. I'm also pretty sure it's correct, so they can't have downvoted because it's wrong! Maybe a mis-click?

Comment: @WendiKidd Thanks for the feedback, I didn't know that...