# When is it okay to ask the same question again?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I previously ask a question about the SO licence and it came up that something like that was ask already 3 years ago. I checked the Q & A's before but most likely missed it.

As a result of that, I've got some down votes and the question was marked as duplicate. Nothing which I prefer but I'm not here for the points...
I do understand the idea of marking questions as duplicates but what's about the fact that this question was asked 3 years ago. What about the possibility that things might have changed since that answer and that it might be not valid anymore.

I'm sure that there are a number of answer which are not up to date anymore. So if the answer is not valid anymore, how to avoid that your question gets marked as a duplicate?

Comment: I think if the old answers are now outdated then posting a new answer on the original would be the best way forward. But if something specific makes the old question non compatible with your question then mention that incompatibility in your question

Comment: You can put a bounty on the old question to draw attention to it and possibly get a newer answer.

Comment: Looking at what I presume is the [question in question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197219/is-the-stackexchange-forum-template-available-for-other-websites-than-their-netw), given that the accepted/most upvoted answer on that question is flat out wrong I'm not wildly comfortable with the situation